# How to add and expand all / collapse all to a jQuery TreeTable in an Apache Wicket application?

Tags: jquery, apache, wicket

I am using the jQuery plugin [TreeTable](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/index.html#example-2) in a similar manner mentioned in blog entry *[A jQuery tree table for Wicket](http://javathoughts.capesugarbird.com/2009/03/jquery-tree-table-for-wicket.html)* .

What I want to do now is attaching some JavaScript code in an expand all / collapse all button(s).

The following code doesn't seem to work.

```
$(".treeTable").treeTable().expand();
```

And also

```
$(".treeTable").treeTable();
$(".treeTable").expand();
```

Comment: Those look correct.  Can you post the markup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very nice challenge.

I've built an 'expand all' feature (because it doesn't have it). Here you have it:

```
$.fn.expandAll = function() {
    $(this).find("tr").removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded").each(function(){
        $(this).expand();
    });
};
```

To use it, just do:

```
$(".treeTable").expandAll();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That did the job! Thanks a lot! :)
I'm new to jQuery, I'm assuming what your function does is to find all tr tags that have class "collapsed", remove that class and apply the "expanded" class on those tr tags.
Again many thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for anyone still looking for this:

You need to trigger these events somehow, e.g: let's say you put two href tags, here's the compatible code:

For expanding all nodes:

```
$('#expandAllTasks').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.gantt_treetable').treetable('expandAll');
});
```

For collapsing all nodes:

```
$('#collapseAllTasks').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.gantt_treetable').treetable('collapseAll');
});
```

I hope this helps someone :)